# Нагрузка на сервер

Tags: php

Доброго времени суток! Существует некий проект, все данные хранятся в БД MySQL. Некоторые таблицы зависят от других. 
Например, есть таблица users - в ней хранится логин, пароль. И есть таблица users_inform - в ней хранятся данные о некоем пользователе (имя, фамилия, пол и т.д). При выводе на страницу мне приходится считывать данные из 2х и более таблиц, добавлять в другие, так же каждые пять секунд обновлять текущие новыми данными, причем если все это совершается для каждого пользователя и их более 6к онлайн. В общем, все действия вызывают неплохую такую нагрузку на сервер :( И возникает вопрос:

1. Какими методами, способами можно в разы сократить нагрузку на сервер, если соединение некоторых таблиц в одну не подходит?
2. Какие ваши методы решения данной проблемы?
3. Что, на ваш взгляд, будет более целесообразным?

P.S проект мобильный (WAP)  и решение в виде js и т.д не катит...

Answer (score 1):

1. Нужно найти самые тяжелые запросы, например, используя EXPLAIN, попытаться их оптимизировать.
2. Там где идет какая либо выборка сделать индексы для полей.
3. По возможности удалить неактуальные записи в БД, тем самым снизив нагрузку
4. Обновить железо ))

Всё это, конечно, очень общие слова, конкретика возможна при другой постановке вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Таблицы объединять не нужно. Но добавить индексов к записям можно! Это делает таблицы больше, но работу с ними быстрее, или же искользовать другой engine для таблиц, например InnoDB, который быстрее работает с выборками.
Конечно же оптимизировать запросы, заменив, например BEETWEEN (a,b) на val=>a AND val<=b и другие медленные запросы.
Почитайте [это](http://phpclub.ru/detail/article/mysql_optimize) и [вот это](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/mysql/41968/)